# Раскрытие и скрытие блоков

Tags: jquery, javascript

Есть код, который, по идеи, скрывает и показывает блок с фильтром. Но он только открывается и больше не закрывается.

```
function ShowHideFastFilter()
{
    if(document.getElementById('all_form_fast_filter').style.display=='none')   {$("#catalog_fast_filter").attr('innerHTML','скрыть'); $("#all_form_fast_filter").show("slow"); return;}
    if(document.getElementById('all_form_fast_filter').style.display=='block')  {$("#catalog_fast_filter").attr('innerHTML','отобразить'); $("#all_form_fast_filter").hide("slow");  return;}
}
function ShowHideSectionFilter()
{
    if(document.getElementById('all_form_section_filter').style.display=='none')    {$("#catalog_section_filter").attr('innerHTML','скрыть'); $("#all_form_section_filter").show("slow"); return;}
    if(document.getElementById('all_form_section_filter').style.display=='block')   {$("#catalog_section_filter").attr('innerHTML','отобразить'); $("#all_form_section_filter").hide("slow");  return;}
}
```

В чем я ошибся?

[Здесь](http://www.gsmall.ru/catalog/243/) результат работы. Под навигацией "Быстрый фильтр".

Comment: Боже мой, такая мешанина plain js и jQ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if ( $('#all_form_fast_filter').is(':visible') ) {
  $("#catalog_fast_filter").text('отобразить');
  $("#all_form_fast_filter").hide("slow");
  } else {
  $("#catalog_fast_filter").text('скрыть');
  $("#all_form_fast_filter").show("slow");
  }
```

Это первая функция, далее по аналогии

Answer (score 0):

Такое чувство что вы перепутали `block` и `none` местами, и код получается какой-то сложный. по нескольку раз одно и то-же проверяете.

Answer (score 0):

Можно так:

```
<div>
  <div>
    <span
      onclick = "
        this.style.display = 'none';
        this.nextElementSibling.style.display = '';
        this.parentElement.nextElementSibling.style.display = '';
      "
      style = 'display: none;'
    >
      Показать
    </span>
    <span
       onclick = "
        this.style.display = 'none';
        this.previousElementSibling.style.display = '';
        this.parentElement.nextElementSibling.style.display = 'none';
      "
    >
      Скрыть
    </span>
  </div>
  <div>
    Моё содержимое
  </div>
</div>
```

Можно функцией, но менять содержимое - ни в коем случае

P.S: Я не сторонник длинного inline JS, только как пример!!!